# Linux process defunct if started from flask

Tags: python, linux, flask, process

I would need my flask application to manage the execution of some commands via a specific endpoint. I would also like to have a second endpoint that allows me to monitor the processes triggered by the flask application.

I already have in my mind about how to do it, I am facing only one problem, after the process execution is finished, the spwaned process remains as **defunct**. How can I solve it?

[image]

I know this depends on the fact that the application that creates the process (i.e. my flask application) continues to exist

I tried to work around the problem by trying to start the process differently and also by trying to force-terminate it, but that didn't work.

```
try:
    res = Popen("my_script.sh",
        universal_newlines=True,
        start_new_session=True,
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=STDOUT,
        cwd="/",
        shell=True,
        env=environ.copy(),
        close_fds=True
    )
    #this function try to handle te process termination
    #it must be a different process as the application must be able to return a response while the process runs in the background
    multiprocessing.Process(target=_ManagerExecutor.__handle_process, args=(res,)).start()
    return result
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

```
@classmethod
def __handle_process(cls, process: Popen):
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if not output:
            break
        #... other app logic
    process.poll()
    result: bool = process.returncode != 0
    try:
        #try force kill, but doesn't work
        killpg(getpgid(process.pid), SIGTERM)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: it's a solution that I found on a blog, I initially tried without it but I still get the same result

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem without Flask, but did not get a zombie process. Do you have an example that can run without Flask, or are you certain, that it happens only when run as a Flask app?

Comment: Even I was only able to reproduce the error using flask. The problem apparently arose from the fact that to start the process asynchronously, and therefore to allow the flask server to return the response, I used the multiprocessing library. I replaced the multiprocessing library with a thread (which allowed me to achieve the same solution), and the problem was solved. I then modified this line: `multiprocessing.Process(target=_ManagerExecutor.__handle_process, args=(res,)).start()`
like this: `Thread(target=_ManagerExecutor.__handle_process, args=(res,), daemon=False).start()`